# Como fechar menu clicando fora ou em qualquer parte da página?

Tags: javascript, html, menu

Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer com que esse menu feche ao clicar fora, ou em qualquer parte da página?

Pois está fechando só se clicar em `.button` do menu.

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('isOpen');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 500 .9rem/1 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
  background: #2f323e;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.sidebar.isOpen {
  transform: translateX(-220px);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button svg {
  width: 40px;
}

.button line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.nav li a::before {
  font: 14px fontawesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a::before { content: '\f00a'; }
.nav li:nth-child(2) a::before { content: '\f012'; }
.nav li:nth-child(3) a::before { content: '\f0e8'; }
.nav li:nth-child(4) a::before { content: '\f0c3'; }
.nav li:nth-child(5) a::before { content: '\f022'; }
.nav li:nth-child(6) a::before { content: '\f115'; }
.nav li:nth-child(7) a::before { content: '\f085'; }
.nav li:nth-child(8) a::before { content: '\f023'; left: 23px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar isOpen">

      <a class="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 215px;  position: absolute;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20" />
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" />
            <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="80" />
         </svg>
        </a>
        
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a>Charts</a></li>
      <li><a>Milestones</a></li>
      <li><a>Lab</a></li>
      <li><a>Preview</a></li>
      <li><a>Assets</a></li>
      <li><a>Settings</a></li>
      <li><a>Logout</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vc pode ao mesmo tempo que abre a `sidebar` tb "abrir" um elemento por traz da `sidebar` que vai cobrir a tela inteira e vai servir para fechar o menu caso seja clicado. Eu chamei esse elemento de `.fechaMenu` e quando vc clica para abrir a `navbar` ele aparece, e se vc clicar nele ele some e fecha a `navbar`. Pra isso usei o *toggle class* com a classe .`isClose` que tem um `display:none` para remover o `.fechaMenu`

Tb coloquei um `z-index` de 2 na `navbar` e de 1 no `.fechaMenu`, assim ele sempre abre por cima de tudo que estiver abaixo, só não fica acima da `.navbar`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como vc vai ver no JS o princípio usado é o mesmo que vc usou no `btn` do *hamburger menu* Eu deixei o `.fechaMenu` com uma cor, mas vc pode deixar ele completamente transparente no CSS é só colocar `rgba(0,0,0,0)` na cor do `background` que ele não fica visível, porém continua ativo e fechando a `navbar` corretamente.

Deixei os comments no código

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('isOpen');
  document.querySelector('.fechaMenu').classList.toggle('isClose');
});

// eventos para fechar o menu, ele basicamente faz o inverso do script anterior
//quando vc clicar no elemento .fechaMenu

document.querySelector('.fechaMenu').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('isOpen');
  document.querySelector('.fechaMenu').classList.toggle('isClose');
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 500 .9rem/1 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
  background: #2f323e;
  height: 100vh;

  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.sidebar.isOpen {
  transform: translateX(-220px);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button svg {
  width: 40px;
}

.button line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.nav li a::before {
  font: 14px fontawesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a::before { content: '\f00a'; }
.nav li:nth-child(2) a::before { content: '\f012'; }
.nav li:nth-child(3) a::before { content: '\f0e8'; }
.nav li:nth-child(4) a::before { content: '\f0c3'; }
.nav li:nth-child(5) a::before { content: '\f022'; }
.nav li:nth-child(6) a::before { content: '\f115'; }
.nav li:nth-child(7) a::before { content: '\f085'; }
.nav li:nth-child(8) a::before { content: '\f023'; left: 23px; }

/* classes do elemento que vai abrir por baixo da navbar e se clicado fecha o menu */
.fechaMenu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  z-index: 1;
}
.isClose {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar isOpen">

      <a class="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 215px;  position: absolute;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20" />
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" />
            <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="80" />
         </svg>
        </a>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a>Charts</a></li>
      <li><a>Milestones</a></li>
      <li><a>Lab</a></li>
      <li><a>Preview</a></li>
      <li><a>Assets</a></li>
      <li><a>Settings</a></li>
      <li><a>Logout</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
<!-- elemento que quando o menu abre ele aparece, e se clicado ele some e fecha o menu -->
  <div class="fechaMenu isClose"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: muito bom meu amigo, muito obrigado pela ajuda, show de bola!

Comment: @AndréMalveira que bom que deu certo! Se alguma resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta :) Assim o site não fica com perguntas abertas pendentes sem resposta aceita. Basta vc escolher a resposta que acredita que resolveu melhor o seu problema e marcar o ✔, vc só pode marcar uma resposta infelizmente.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar se o click foi originário de fora do sidebar criando um *event handler* para o objeto window quando qualquer elemento da página for clicado (veja comentários explicativos no código):

```js
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', () => {
   document.querySelector('.sidebar').classList.toggle('isOpen');
});

window.onclick = (e) =>{
   
   // seleciona o .sidebar
   let sid = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
   
   // verifica se está fechado ou aberto
   let ope = sid.classList.contains('isOpen');

   // verifica se o elemento clicado contém a classe .sidebar
   let alv = e.target.classList.contains('sidebar');
   
   // verifica se o elemento clicado é filho de .sidebar
   let pai = e.target.closest('.sidebar');

   // se tudo for falso, fecha o sidebar
   if(!ope && !alv && !pai) sid.classList.toggle('isOpen');
   
}
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  font: 500 .9rem/1 'Avenir Next', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
  background: #2f323e;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #000;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: transform .3s;
}

.sidebar.isOpen {
  transform: translateX(-220px);
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button svg {
  width: 40px;
}

.button line {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 5;
}

h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 16px 0 16px 50px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.nav li a:hover,
.nav li a.active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.nav li a::before {
  font: 14px fontawesome;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 20px;
}

.nav li:nth-child(1) a::before { content: '\f00a'; }
.nav li:nth-child(2) a::before { content: '\f012'; }
.nav li:nth-child(3) a::before { content: '\f0e8'; }
.nav li:nth-child(4) a::before { content: '\f0c3'; }
.nav li:nth-child(5) a::before { content: '\f022'; }
.nav li:nth-child(6) a::before { content: '\f115'; }
.nav li:nth-child(7) a::before { content: '\f085'; }
.nav li:nth-child(8) a::before { content: '\f023'; left: 23px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar isOpen">

      <a class="button" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 215px;  position: absolute;">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
            <line x1="0" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20" />
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" />
            <line x1="0" y1="80" x2="100" y2="80" />
         </svg>
        </a>
        
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a class="active">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a>Charts</a></li>
      <li><a>Milestones</a></li>
      <li><a>Lab</a></li>
      <li><a>Preview</a></li>
      <li><a>Assets</a></li>
      <li><a>Settings</a></li>
      <li><a>Logout</a></li>
    </ul> 
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: muito bom tbm meu amigo, obrigado pela sua ajuda, esse seu tbm ta show de bola!

Comment: De nada colega! Boa sorte aí nos seus códigos! :D