# Problemas com menu mobile

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Gente estou com um probleminha no menu lateral que criei na versão mobile do meu [site](http://creativestudiodesigner.com.br/test/99run/) precisava que quando a pessoa abri-se o menu e clica-se fora ele fechasse como mostra a imagem abaixo, no caso isso não acontece atualmente e não sei o porque segue o meu script que faz o menu funcionar.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

JS:

```
jQuery(function ($) {

  $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});
});
```

Comment: Cara posta um código mínimo que de par a pelo menos simular seu problemas, inclua o html e CSS

Comment: @hugocsl vou inserir aqui per aai

Comment: @hugocsl eu inseri o link do site na descrição lá da para ver o que acontece mas olha na versão mobile por favor

Comment: Sem seu código não da para ajudar muito, mas esse pergunta duplicada responde exatamente isso, e tem uma técnica que vc pode usar no seu código facilmente. Basicamente quando vc abre o menu vc tb coloca por tras dele um div cobrindo a tela toda de baixo, se clicar nela fecha o menu https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365451/como-fechar-menu-clicando-fora-ou-em-qualquer-parte-da-página/